# Could currentBackgroundColor become a valid CSS color-value keyword?

Tags: css, colors, w3c

CSS [defines](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor) `currentColor` as a color equivalent to an element’s `color` property. It’s similar to a CSS variable, but on a per-element basis. When `currentColor` is used as a color value in any CSS property, it computes to whatever is the `color` value for the element to which it is applied.

So, my question is not whether something `currentBackgroundColor` *exists*—I have combed through the [CSS Color specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) and am fairly confident it does not—but whether it *could* exist.

Borrowing from the `currentColor` definition, I presume `currentBackgroundColor` would be defined as something like:

> The value of the ‘background-color’ property. The computed value of the ‘currentBackgroundColor’ keyword is the computed value of the ‘background-color’ property. If the ‘currentBackgroundColor’ keyword is set on the ‘background-color’ property itself, it is treated as ‘background-color: inherit’.

Can anyone point to any implementation issues which I may not be considering?

Comment: On another burner in my mind, I’ve been pondering a similar `currentBorder[Top|Left|Right|Bottom]Color` property. A `currentBorderColor` would feel much simpler, but it would have to be arbitrarily defined which value it computes to when not all border sides are colored identically, and that could lead to some confusion.

Comment: TL;DR, thanks to CSS variables a keyword like this isn't "useless" but certainly not necessary. I would've liked and appreciated a `currentBackgroundColor`, especially because CSS has things like `:any-link` but a `currentBorderXColor` is just taking the piss considering it's not necessary in the first place, especially as it could lead to an endless number of unnecessary keywords: `currentBorderRadius`, `currentPaddingX`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it could. For example, it would make it very easy to create an section of your text inverted-colour, ie you could swap the foreground and background colours to highlight something.

However, suggesting this as a CSS feature would be fighting against the tide. There used to be a whole bunch of CSS colour keywords, for things like the scrollbar colour, and the standard button colour, and the colours of the 3D shadows on the buttons... but they were all dropped from CSS some time ago.

There are lots of things in CSS that could be useful that aren't in there. Personally I'm more excited about CSS variables. When they become mainstream we are unlikely to be too worried about colour keywords like this

Answer (score 11):

> Can anyone point to any implementation issues which I may not be considering?

Yes. There could be circular dependencies:

```
* {
  background-color: currentColor;
  color: currentBackgroundColor;
}
```

Moreover, `currentcolor` can be useful because text has a single color. But backgrounds can have additional things like background-images and such, which might counterintuitively leave `background-color` set to the default of `transparent`. And then `currentBackgroundColor`  is not much useful.

Comment: Great call. Hadn’t considered the circular reference scenario. And I could see how the initial value of `background-color` being `transparent` might make my proposed keyword a bit awkward to use except in certain situations, but I don't find that altogether offputting.

Comment: I mentioned swapping the colours as well. But an interesting point -- at what point do changes to the variables take effect? Because if the first line of your code changes the background variable immediately, then the second line won't do what you want it to do. With the complexities of overrides, cascades and selector specificity, I can see this could actually be quite a difficult one to work out; the code above really isn't as simple as it looks. Maybe this is why it was left out of the spec in the first place.

Comment: I'm revisiting this and thinking some more about it. I think your circular dependency point is still valid, but not your concern about non-color backgrounds. CSS defines `background-color` as a single `<color>`. `<image>`s and `<gradient>`s are invalid `background-colors` and *must* be set as a `background-image`. So if you set a background image or gradient, you are not in any way changing the `background-color`, though you may be effectively "hiding" it.

Comment: Additionally, take buttons for example.  Or swaths of text.  Plenty of websites have a plain background for the actual body, but almost every non-transparent element on the page has some sort of plain background-color.  My primary interest in this is making border colors match background colors to make the border disappear without changing the size it takes up.

Comment: Just because there is one way in which it could be invalid, doesnt mean there aren't hundreds of ways in which it would be really useful. You can write lots of invalid CSS, it just fails to render. e.g. `color: 100px;`

Comment: Adding to what @JacobFord and @run_the_race said, note that there'd be a way to make `background-color: currentColor; color: currentBackgroundColor;` valid. In this case, both `currentColor` and `currentBackgroundColor` could refer to the parent element's (background) color, like is already the case when setting `color: currentColor`: "If currentcolor is used as the value of the color property, it instead takes its value from the inherited value of the color property." ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword))

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly many cases where currentBackgroundColor would be very useful.
Alternative techniques I've used are...

1. CSS Custom Properties (CSS Variables), eg --backgroundColor.
2. Make use of currentColor to set background-color. This approach is only possible on containers (and specific children) that are not using the foreground colour. Child elements can inherit color and set background-color:currentColor.

Comment: This does not answer the question: OP asked for issues with it, not ways it could be used successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `currentBackgroundColor` keyword could exist and was [proposed in 2020](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5292). However, it does not yet exist.

I've had luck implementing the same effect using the `Canvas` [system color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/system-color#canvas), which is defined as the "background of application content or documents". Just to be safe, I also set the text color to `CanvasColor` to ensure I'm not accidentally implementing white-on-white or black-on-black.

However, this will *not* reflect the page's CSS—even `body { background-color:purple; }`. All it does is key on the system's configuration. It does seem to match the default "dark mode" coloring scheme, which solves my particular problem.

Example implementation:

```css
p       { padding:1ex; }
.purple { background-color:rebeccapurple; color:#fff; }
.canvas { background-color:Canvas; color:CanvasText; }
```

```html
<p class="purple">
  This block is white on purple.
  <span class="canvas">This sentence uses "Canvas" coloring.</span> 
  This sentence does not.
</p>
<p>This is normal text.</p>
```

Comment: @TylerH – Stack Overflow is a programming site. This question asked if something could exist, which is not really a programming question. I interpreted the question as "how can I get something _like_ `currentBackgroundColor` since that does not exist?". I'll edit my answer to make that more clear.